# SMPT MAIL SENDING ERROR WITH ASP CLASSIC

Tags: email, asp-classic, smtp

I'm trying to send mail from my webserver to other mail services using smtp. i search the net and i found a code for doing that. so i created a sample page called cdosys.asp which after that i place on my godaddy server and added the neccesary smtp addresses but when i send it gives me and error.

error '8004020e'

/cdosys.asp, line 42

```
<%
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '
    '   Send email using the CDOSYS component
    '
    '   by Chris Hardy
    '   http://www.chrishardy.co.uk/
    '
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Option Explicit

  dim sName, sEmail, sMessage
    dim oCdoMail, oCdoConf, sConfURL

  if Request.Form("Action") <> "" then
    sName = Request.Form("Name")
    sEmail = Request.Form("Email")
    sMessage = Request.Form("Message")

        Set oCdoMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        Set oCdoConf = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

        sConfURL = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"

        with oCdoConf
            .Fields.Item(sConfURL & "sendusing") = 2
            .Fields.Item(sConfURL & "smtpserver") = "smtpout.secureserver.net"
            .Fields.Item(sConfURL & "smtpserverport") = 80
            .Fields.Update


        end with

        with oCdoMail
            .From = "noreply@myserver.com"
            .To = sEmail
            .Subject = "My message subject"
            .TextBody = sMessage
            .HTMLBody = sMessage
            .Configuration = oCdoConf
            .Send
        end with

        Set oCdoConf = Nothing
        Set oCdoMail = Nothing

    response.write "Thanks for your message!"
  else
%>
<form method="post" action="<%=Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")%>">
<p>Name:<br /><input type="text" name="Name" /></p>
<p>E-mail:<br /><input type="text" name="Email" /></p>
<p>Message:<br /><textarea name="Message"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="Action" value="Send" /></p>
</form>
<%
  end if
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you try a few things:

1 - Ensure that the From address is valid.

2 - Try using a From address that is a valid account with your mail server secureserver.net.

3 - Ensure the To address is valid.

4 - Try authenticating with the SMTP server using a valid account and password, like this:

```
oCdoMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
oCdoMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="somemail@yourserver.com"
oCdoMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="yourpassword"
```

5 - According to [Godaddy support](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4219/using-cdo-to-send-email-from-your-windows-shared-hosting-web-site) you may be only able to send email using their mail server relay-hosting.secureserver.net. Perhaps they block port 25 SMTP traffic. Here is their code sample:

```
<%
sendUrl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing"
smtpUrl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver"


' Set the mail server configuration
Set objConfig=CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
objConfig.Fields.Item(sendUrl)=2 ' cdoSendUsingPort
objConfig.Fields.Item(smtpUrl)="relay-hosting.secureserver.net"
objConfig.Fields.Update


' Create and send the mail
Set objMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
' Use the config object created above
Set objMail.Configuration=objConfig
objMail.From="sender@coolexample.com"
objMail.ReplyTo="sender@coolexample.com"
objMail.To="recipient@coolexample.com"
objMail.Subject="subject"
objMail.TextBody="body"
objMail.Send
%>
```

Comment: Looks like Godaddy have a specific mail server that you must use. See number 5 in my editted answer.

Comment: I wish I could give you 100 points for this answer